# Spring bean definition null reference

Tags: spring

```
public class A{
  private B b;
}

public class B{
}
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="aBean" class="A">
<property name="b">  ???  </property>
</bean>
```

How to create an instance of A with b = null when using `context.getBean("aBean")`?

I have tried `<property name="b"><null/></property>`, but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Actually it will be null by default. No need for specific configuration, i.e. just omit `<property>` element.

And actually

```
<bean id="aBean" class="A">
  <property name="b"><null /></property>
</bean>
```

**should** work: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-null-element

Answer (score -1):

Huh? Just don't do anything.

```
<bean id="aBean" class="A"/>
```

In Java [object references are null by default](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=14).

Comment: I'd appreciate if those who downvote an answer also left a comment stating _why_ they think the answer is inappropriate/incorrect.